# UIButton setAttributedTitle: mutableString forState: on ios5

Tags: ios, uibutton

is there any hack to run setAttributedTitle on iOS 5? That is iOS6 feature, but I need backward compatibility.

When i using this on iOS 5

```
[self setAttributedTitle:mutableString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

i receive error:

```
[UIButton setAttributedTitle:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to look at creating a custom button and using [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) to create the label (`DTAttributedLabel`) to go onto it.